# Reactjs Infinite Scroll

Tags: reactjs

I'm gonna lose my mind.

I'm trying to define that; when my scroll reaches the end of my div, I want to add more content.

But I couldn't define the "end of the div" because react focuses only page and window.
I want that; "my scroll reaches my element, and the end of it."

(I'm not scrolling inside my element. I'm scrolling body. And define that, my body scroll reaches the element's end)

```
 const isScrolling =()=>{
        if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop!==document.documentElement.offsetHeight){
          return;
        }
        nextPage()
      }
```

here's my element that I want to define. (.i-want-to-reach-that)

```
<GeneralLayout aboutOverlay={false} headerData={header_data}>
    <div className="row i-want-to-reach-that">
      <div className="col-sm-12">
        <div className="row">
          {product_list.data.map((item, i) => (
            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
              <ProductCard {...item} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
</GeneralLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel.

Use `react-infinite-scroll-component` library.

Go to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component) page and see instructions for usage.

**Edit:**

Check [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/w3w89k7x8?file=/src/index.js:987-990) which applies infinite scrolling at a div.

Comment: it looks like, it works with "div scroll". I want to make infinite scroll with Body scroll. not inner scroll.

Comment: Check the new demo link.